# How to stop MainLoop in Perl/Tk + AnyEvent

Tags: perl, tk-toolkit, anyevent

I'm writing Perl/Tk program which uses AnyEvent's timer. And I have a problem with closing window if timer is active. I made this window close handler:

```
$self -> {window} -> protocol( 'WM_DELETE_WINDOW' => sub {
                                                   undef $self -> {timer};
                                                   $self -> {window} -> destroy;
});
```

If timer is active when I close the window, timer stops, window closes, but MainLoop doesn't stop. What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the `AnyEvent::Impl::Tk` documentation, a hidden Tk MainWindow is created to get things working. But it seems that this hidden window is never destroyed automatically. As a workaround, you can do it yourself:

```
$AnyEvent::Impl::Tk::mw->destroy;
```